# How do i send a mail having a link using nodemailer accessible from any network

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am able to send a link to any email id. But the link is not accessible from any other machine since it belongs to my localhost.

The link is like : `localhost:3000\welcome`

where welcome is my html page. I am sending the mail using `nodemailer` in `nodejs`. But this page cannot be viewed in some other network.
I want that the link of the page that I am sending on clicking it, the page should open be it any network.

Answer (score 2):

You simply get the network name (hostname) of the system and then add it to the text of the mail you are sending.

```
var hostName = require('os').hostname();
```

Then the SMTP should look something like this:

```
var text = "http://"+hostName+":3000/welcome"
var mailOptions = {
        from: "Sender <sender@test.com>", // sender address
        to: destination_email,
        subject: "Subject here",
        html: text // html body
    };
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            logger.logError(error);
            callback(null);
            return;   
        }
        logger.logInfo("Message sent: " + response.message);

    });
```